# Can I use an old cog for my new hub?

Tags: hub, conversion, sprocket, coaster, flip-flop-hub

I have an old wheelset with a 16T cog. It's currently a 120mm flipflop hub, and I'm going to be replacing it with a 120mm coaster. The coaster hub that I want doesn't come with a 16T cog (only 14, 15 and 17 for some reason).

Rather than mess around with chain tension, etc, I was wondering if I could just use the cog from the old wheelset on the new hub, or if it's more complicated than that.

More info: old hub is a 32H, 14G, 16T cog. New hub is a velosteel 32H http://www.elegantwheels.net/STORE.html

Comment: can you tell use the model of the new hub. But I don't believe you can use it although most coaster hubs you can switch out the cog. I know you can on a strumey archer S2C

Comment: As stated on that website, you can bolt on any 16t fixie/track cog on there.

Comment: You have to "mess around with chain tension" every time you remove and install the rear wheel on any single-speed bike. Do you not have a horizontal dropouts?

Comment: No amount of messing around with the chain tension would change the gear ratio of a 17 tooth cog to match what you obtained from a 16 tooth cog. The gear ratio is purely the ratio of the tooth count of the driving gear to the tooth count of the sprocket. As far as the actual chain tension goes, you probably want to to be getting a new chain when changing sprockets anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To quote the page you linked, "Since the Velosteel hub has standard track threads, it can run any fixie/track cog built to Phil Wood/Campagnolo standards." For cogs, this is the same standard as every other cog, but the lock ring will probably be different. Just take the cog from your old hub and keep the lock ring from new one.

Note that this is different from most other coaster brake hubs, the more common Shimano, Torpedo and others use splined cogs.

Answer (score 1):

The hub you posted allows you to use standard track cogs, so you should easily be able to swap your 16T cog in and replace whatever it comes with.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will not answer your question but will give some light on working around it. Instead of replacing the cog or messing around with chain tension you can adjust the length of your chain just right by using one of online chain length calculators and possibly a half link. This is what I did with my vertical dropouts modern frame converted to single speed. No tensioner was used and the chain length is perfect, although I had to add a half link. This is my favorite web site calculator which gives you a graphic view of how far from the perfect length you are and if it's on a tight or loose side, and more options if half link is being used: http://eehouse.org/fixin/formfmu.php.

Comment: The calculator is pointless if the OPs frame has horizontal dropouts.